# How this code for parallel task works in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, parallel-processing

I've been using a script (above) to run some task in parallel in an Ubuntu server with 16 processors, it actually works but I have a few questions about it:

- What is the code actually doing?
- As more workers I set up the script run faster, but what is the limit of workers?, I've run 100.
- How could improve it?

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env python
  from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
  from executable import run_model
  from database import DB
  import numpy as np

  def worker(work_queue, db_conection):
      try:
          for phone in iter(work_queue.get, 'STOP'):
              registers_per_number = retrieve_CDRs(phone, db_conection)
              run_model(np.array(registers_per_number), db_conection)
              #print("The phone %s was already run" % (phone))

      except Exception:
          pass

      return True


  def retrieve_CDRs(phone, db_conection):
      return db_conection.retrieve_data_by_person(phone)


  def main():
      phone_numbers = np.genfromtxt("../listado.csv", dtype="int")[:2000]

      workers = 16
      work_queue = Queue()
      processes = []
      #print("Process started with %s" % (workers))

      for phone in phone_numbers:
          work_queue.put(phone)
          #print("Phone %s put at the queue" % (phone))
      #print("The queue %s" % (work_queue))

      for w in xrange(workers):
          #print("The worker %s" % (w))
          # new conection to data base
          db_conection = DB()
          p = Process(target=worker, args=(work_queue, db_conection))

          p.start()
          #print("Process %s started" % (p))
          processes.append(p)
          work_queue.put('STOP')

      for p in processes:
          p.join()


  if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
  ```

  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

At first, start from the main function:

1. It's creating an numpy array of 2000 integers type phone numbers from a CSV file.
2. Then creating some variables and lists.
3. Next, you are creating a queue with all the phone numbers that you extracted from the CSV file
4. Next, for the 16 workers, you are creating a DB connection for each, setting up the processing arguments and started the process for all the worker processors.

Hope that helps you to understand the code. Actually, it's kind of multi-threading you are trying and it's behaving like parallel processing. So, the more number you use, it becomes more faster. You should be able to use 2000 processors as my common sense says that. After that it's not meaningful as master-slave philosophy. Also, parallel processing suggests you to minimize the number of idle processors/workers. If you have more than 2000 workers, then you will have some idle workers which will reduce your performance. Finally, improving parallel processing needs to improve this kind of ideology.

Hope that helps. Cheers!